# want field in database contains ids of users that is participant in php

Tags: php, database

php

i have Champions Table AND Want people attend the champion then add to the players field in this table  Got it ? I think its using array or Relationship IDK So 
What Gonna Do WHEN He Click in attend Button What is the code 
 i Think

```
$id = 1;// as example 

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT pid FROM champions WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1");

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$pid = 1;// as example 
$sql = "INSERT INTO champions (pid) VALUES ('$row['pid']."|".$pid')";//pid = playersid
      $conn->query($sql)
```

Actually IDK if this code working or not it doesnt matter 
 the matter here is how to retreive the pid  and get id of Every user Separately
Thanx :)

Comment: this question is not very clear can you elaborate further on what you are trying to do please?

Comment: sorry its missing click i will type again

Comment: can you paste some outputs that you have so far, and table structures, I can then suggest some ammendments

Comment: what i want to do 
Table named Champions 
this contains every Competition that i make 

every row is Competition
i want column in the row contains the id of the players that will attend 
like that 

"1 | 14 | 16 | 5"
where the numbers is id of the players 
My question is how to retreive every id Separately and got details from another table like his name and points ...etc  
Thanx

Comment: can you paste what the query is currently returning please? i'm assuming its only returning one record

Comment: Thats it 
"5 | 16 | 17 | 98 | 34"
i want Every number Separately

Comment: the column is Text Type not int so we have numbers and |

Comment: i think i got it 
$pid  = "5 | 16 | 17 | 98 | 34" ;
$id= explode(" | ", $pid );
echo $id[0]; // 5
echo $id[1]; // 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got it

```
$pid  = "5 | 16 | 17 | 98 | 34" ;
$id= explode(" | ", $pid );
echo $id[0]; // 5
echo $id[1]; // 16
```

Thanx for trying to help me